# Unable to use gulp-mocha with babel 6

Tags: gulp, mocha.js, babeljs

I am trying to use gulp-babel with gulp-mocha as following:

```
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('test', function() {
  return gulp.src('test/*.js', {read: false})
    .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}))
    .pipe(mocha());
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work, with error such as

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {assert}
                                                              ^^^^^^
Unexpected reserved word
```

I have documented this case here https://github.com/tnguyen14/babel-gulp-mocha-test

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong? Any help would be hugely appreciated.

EDIT: please try this with node 0.12. Node 4.x will just work, but won't prove anything as it already supports the ES2015 method in the test here, i.e. `endsWith`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was missing is `babel-polyfill`. The `es2015` preset does not provide new ES2015 functionality, it just helps with the newer syntax.

Adding the polyfill solves this problem. See more details at this issue here https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2967

Answer (score 1):

It works with the following, combined with .babelrc:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var mocha = require('gulp-mocha');
require("babel-core/register");

gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src('test/*.js', {read: false})
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(mocha({
            ui: 'tdd'
        }));
});
```

Comment: I just tried that and it isn't working. which version of node are you using? I am seeing this issue on node 0.12 (which does not support `endsWith`, which is the whole point of using babel for).